# I need to compare an array to another and create different lists based on that - flutter / dart

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I have two arrays in one class (data-- categorydata and storydata).
I have another stateless widget where I need to compare these two arrays (their categories) and based on the category, create a different list.

```
const categorydata = [
  CategoryTemplate(screen: 'story', title: 'Calm down', category: 'ca', color: Colors.blue ),

  CategoryTemplate(screen: 'story', title: 'Meditation', category: 'me', color: Colors.orange ),

  CategoryTemplate(screen: 'story', title: 'Self confidence', category: 'se', color: Colors.green ),
];

const storydata = [
  StoryTemplate(
    id: 's1', 
    categoryId: [ 'ca', 'me' ], 
    title: 'Title 1', ),

    StoryTemplate(
    id: 's2', 
    categoryId: [ 'se', 'me' ], 
    title: 'Title2', ),
];
```

then my widget and class look like this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../models/dummy_data.dart';

class CategoryItem extends StatelessWidget {

  final String title;
  final Color color;
  final String mycategory;

  const CategoryItem ({ Key? key, required this.color, required this.title , required this.mycategory}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context ) {
   
    // I WANT TO COMPARE BOTH OF THEM HERE SO I CAN USE THEM FOR CREATING THE WIDGET LISTS

    // I CANT FIND A WAY TO OBTAIN category FROM categorydata SO IT CA BE USED TO
    // CHECK IF THEY'RE THE SAME AS categoryId FROM storydata. AND AT THE SAME TIME BE 
    // USED AS itemCount: categoryStories.length.

    final categoryStories = storydata.where((story){
      return story.categoryId.contains(categoryTotal); 
    }).toList();

    return Container (
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, bottom: 10),
            child: Text(title),
          ),

          Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, top: 5, bottom: 15),
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemBuilder: (ctx, index){

               // I'VE TRIED TO INCLUDE IT HERE SO I CAN HAVE THE INDEX TO CHECK 
               //categorydata BUT IF I DO THAT I LOSE THE VARIABLE FOR itemCount: DUE TO 
               //SCOPE

              final categoryStories = storydata.where((story){ 
               return story.categoryId.contains(categorydata[index].category);
               }).toList();

               return Text(categoryStories[index].title);
            }, 
              itemCount: categoryStories.length,
            )
            ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I want to compare these two arrays' categorydata and storydata so I can create new lists based on their categories. If both of them are equal, then the list is created.
If I access it at the beginning (outside the listview builder), then I don't know how to access the category in categorydata. If I instead try to access inside the listview, I have the index to check every category in categorydata but I lose the variable to check the item count.

I hope you can help me! Thanks in advance

Comment: I am slightly confused here. Could you clarify/elaborate the requirements here? What is the expected output?  `I want to compare these two arrays categorydata and storydata so I can create new lists based on their categories.`

Comment: Thanks for your reply..
I want to create a listView, where I can separate by CATEGORY: calm down (with category 'ca'), meditation (category 'me'), self confidence (category 'se').. 
and where each storyTemplate that has a certain category can be assigned to the CATEGORY 

So in this case will be 

Calm down
    StoryTemplate: id: s1 
Meditation 
     StoryTemplate: id: s1 and  id: s2
Self confidence
      StoryTemplate id:s2

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you wanted to have a list of `Category Templates` with list of associated `Story Templates` listed in a `ListView`.

One of the many approaches is to create a Map object like this `Map<CategoryTemplate, List<StoryTemplate>>` and then pass this to `ListView`. Now, this is not as neat as it could be as `ListView` is intended for plain Lists. The way you could approach this is to extend the `Category Template` to include `Story Templates` as a instance variable.

In this situation I have decided to provide solution using the Map object I mentioned above as I am unsure of your constraints.

I have created a method that will return a `Map<CategoryTemplate, List<StoryTemplate>>`called `sortByCategories()`.

```
 Map<CategoryTemplate, List<StoryTemplate>> sortByCategories() {
      Map<CategoryTemplate, List<StoryTemplate>> map = {};
      for (var categoryTemplate in categorydata) {
        final matchingStories = storydata
            .where((element) =>
                element.categoryId.contains(categoryTemplate.category))
            .toList();
        map[categoryTemplate] = matchingStories;
      }
      return map;
    }
```

The above method then can be used to get the item count and then by extracting `values` and `keys` alongside `index` from `itemBuilder` function we can extract the details. See the `Container` below from my implementation of `build`

```
     Container(
              height: 300,
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, top: 5, bottom: 15),
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
                  return Card(
                    color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.background,
                    child: Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Text(sortByCategories()
                              .keys
                              .toList()[index]
                              .title),
                          Divider(),
                          ...sortByCategories()
                              .values
                              .toList()[index]
                              .map((storyTemplate) {
                            return Text(storyTemplate.title);
                          }),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
                itemCount: sortByCategories()?.length,
              ),
            ),
```

The final result I had is this

[image]